# How to achieve chain calls with Struct in Swift

Tags: swift

How to achieve a similar chain style with `struct`, do comment if it's a duplicate.

```swift
class Employee {
    
    var name: String?
    var designation: String?
    
    func name(_ name: String) -> Employee {
        self.name = name
        return self
    }
    
    func designation(_ designation: String) -> Employee {
        self.designation = designation
        return self
    }
}

/// Usage
let emp = Employee()
    .name("Speedy")
    .designation("iOS Enigineer")

print(emp.designation)
```

Comment: Why not just `let emp = Employee(name: "Speedy", designation: "iOS Enigineer")`?

Comment: You need to create and return a copy, not self in your functions. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267232/does-swift-optimise-chained-creation-and-copy-of-structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the initialiser of the struct and pass it the given value:

```
struct Employee {
    
    var name: String?
    var designation: String?
    
    func name(_ name: String) -> Employee {
        .init(name: name, designation: self.designation)
    }
    
    func designation(_ designation: String) -> Employee {
        .init(name: self.name, designation: designation)
    }
}
```

If all the methods that you are chaining are boring property setters, you might as well just call the automatically generated initialisers:

```
// either parameter can be omitted!
Employee(name: "...", designation: "...")
```

This sort of chaining is only really useful when there are more complicated things going on with your properties. For example, when 2 properties must be set at the same time, or if you require generic parameters when setting those properties. For a good example of this, see [how SwiftUI does this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-appearance).

See also: [Builder pattern set method in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56180347/5133585)

Comment: Yup seems too much boilerplate code if the attributes are more.

Comment: @RTXGamer You can also try the approach suggested by Tony Nguyen in the linked post, if you think that's too much boilerplate. :)